# New list from the elements of two lists popping sequentially

Tags: python

Can this be shortened, optimised or made more pythonic ?

```
a = [1,9,'foo',5,7]    
b = ['bar',4,8,6]    
c = []

min_len = min(len(a),len(b))

for i in range(min_len):
  c.extend([a.pop(0), b.pop(0)])

c.extend(a)
c.extend(b)

print c
```

output: [1, 'bar', 9, 4, 'foo', 8, 5, 6, 7]

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities...

```
from itertools import chain, izip_longest
def alternate(a, b):
    for i in range(max(len(a), len(b))):
        if i < len(a):
            yield a[i]
        if i < len(b):
            yield b[i]

def alternate2(list_a, list_b):
    unfound = {}
    for a, b in izip_longest(list_a, list_b, fill=unfound):
        if a is not unfound:
            yield a
        if b is not unfound:
            yield b

a = [1,9,'foo',5,7]    
b = ['bar',4,8,6] 
print list(alternate(a, b))
print list(alternate2(a, b))
print list(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b))) + a[len(b):] + b[len(a):]
```

Comment: not sure about those `A`/`B` for local variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write:

```
import itertools

def alternate(xs, ys):
    head = itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(xs, ys))
    return itertools.chain(head, xs[len(ys):], ys[len(xs):])

print(list(alternate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ["a", "b", "c"])))  
# [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 5]
```

Another solution without `itertools` and using the (long-awaited) [yield from](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) construction added in [Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html):

```
def alternate(xs, ys):
    yield from (z for zs in zip(xs, ys) for z in zs)
    yield from (xs[len(ys):] if len(xs) > len(ys) else ys[len(xs):])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid doing `x.pop(0)` because [it is slow](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-queues) (unlike `x.pop()`, by the way).  Instead, I would write (in Python 2):

```
import itertools

def alternate(a, b):
    """Yield alternatingly from two lists, then yield the remainder of the longer list."""
    for A, B in itertools.izip(a, b):
        yield A
        yield B
    for X in a[len(b):] or b[len(a):]:
        yield X

print list(alternate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ["a", "b", "c"]))
```

In Python 3, `itertools.izip` becomes `zip` and, as tokland has noted, we can use [`yield from`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) in Python 3.3:

```
def alternate(a, b):
    """Yield alternatingly from two lists, then yield the remainder of the longer list."""
    for A, B in zip(a, b):
        yield A
        yield B
    yield from a[len(b):] or b[len(a):]

print(list(alternate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ["a", "b", "c"])))
```

The following will work with any kind of iterables:

```
def alternate(a, b):
    """Yield alternatingly from two iterables, then yield the remainder of the longer one."""
    x, y = iter(a), iter(b)
    while True:
        try:
            yield next(x)
        except StopIteration:
            yield from y
            return
        x, y = y, x
```

Answer (score 1):

If the lists cannot contain `None` as a valid item that you want copied to `c`, you can use this:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

c = [item for items in izip_longest(a, b) for item in items if item is not None]
```

It is shorter/concise*, doesn't modify the original lists and probably performs a bit better.

*Yet it doesn't look so elegant, but it's a common pattern in Python, which is most important.

As a bonus, it scales to more lists easily.

Answer (score 0):

Without `pop`, `yield` or `itertools`

```
c = []
for i,x in enumerate(zip(a,b)):     
    c.extend(x)
i += 1
c.extend(a[i:])
c.extend(b[i:])
```

In older versions the loop could be written as a comprehension, but in newer ones `i` is not accessible outside the loop. But:

```
c = [y for x in zip(a,b) for y in x]
i = len(c)//2  # or i = min(len(a),len(b))
c.extend(a[i:])
c.extend(b[i:])
```

At its core, this is a question of how to flatten `zip(a,b)`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python
makes the case that `itertools.chain` is somewhat faster than the comprehension, though not drastically so.

```
c = chain.from_iterable(zip(a,b)) # or
c = chain(*zip(a,b))
```

Comment: Why would one avoid `yield` (a language construct) or `itertools` (batteries included, what Python is famous for)?